# Which ServiceControl.Contracts messages should IHandle?

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus5, nsb-servicecontrol

I'm trying to make sure that 3rd party dependencies are running, and built a service to do this based on the [Monitoring 3rd party Sample Application](http://docs.particular.net/samples/custom-checks/monitoring3rdparty/), which emits ServiceControl CheckResult messages.

This works fine; ServicePulse alerts me when I stop/start my local and remote windows services, Databases, Flux Capacitors, etc.

I now want to build a windows service / nServiceBus Endpoint, like ServicePulse, but with logic that can attempt recovery, send emails etc. I don't really want to put this code into the 3rdParty monitor.

I followed the [servicecontrol/external-integrations](http://docs.particular.net/servicecontrol/external-integrations) and [servicecontrol/contracts](http://docs.particular.net/servicecontrol/contracts) tutorials, and created my *MendStuffOrEmail* endpoint - But it doesn't work; It doesn't receive any messages.

I was going to ask "what am I doing wrong?", but I think I know; I'm using IHandleMessages<ServiceControl.Contracts.MessageFailed> which is for failed messages.

I need to listen for the "CheckResult" type messages - but what are they? I have looked through the ServiceControl and ServicePulse code, but cannot work out what is being sent/received. How can I find this out, or has anyone else actually done this and already knows?

**UPDATE**
After more extensive rummaging, I also subscribed to CustomCheckFailed and CustomCheckSucceeded messages. I implemented IHandle interfaces for them, but I'm still not getting any messages. The log shows autosubscriber has taken out a subscription to them. What should I check for next?

Comment: What version of ServiceControl are you using? 
Any chance you can share your code on github or dropbox?

Here is a sample i built a while back: https://github.com/sfarmar/Presentations/tree/master/LightsOn/MonitoringNotifications

Comment: Its version 1.6.0.0 of ServiceControl.exe and 1.1.0.0 of ServiceControl.ServiceContracts.dll. I've not used either GitHub or Dropbox and any upload will require cleaning / anonymising first - I'll have a look at doing that later tonight. I'll look through your code first though in case there's anything obviously wrong in mine.

Answer (score 0):

I compared my code to Sean's posted 
[example](https://github.com/sfarmar/Presentations/tree/master/LightsOn/MonitoringNotifications) and found the mistake: 
I had implemented two of the interfaces, *IConfigureThisEndpoint* and *AsA_Server* in the wrong class (a 2am cut 'n' paste error).

The example listens for failed messages, but for anyone else trying to do this, you do need to subscribe to *CustomCheckFailed* and *CustomCheckSucceeded* messages (nuget ServiceControl.Contracts).

```
public partial class MessageHandler : IHandleMessages<CustomCheckFailed>,
                                      IHandleMessages<CustomCheckSucceeded>
{
    public void Handle(CustomCheckFailed message)
    {
        this.HandleImplementation(message);
    }
    partial void HandleImplementation(CustomCheckFailed message);

    public void Handle(CustomCheckSucceeded message)
    {
        this.HandleImplementation(message);
    }
    partial void HandleImplementation(CustomCheckSucceeded message);

    public IBus Bus { get; set; }   
}
```

then the logic to do something with the messages. (I left in my original test - sending email - but our system has a library with all sorts of recovery & notification methods. You'll need something similar to stop an email flood):

```
public partial class MessageHandler
{
    partial void HandleImplementation(CustomCheckFailed message)
    {
        var messageBody = string.Format("Message with id {0} failed with reason {1}", message.CustomCheckId, message.FailureReason);
        MailMessageFactory.sendEmail("Failure Notification", messageBody);

        Console.Out.WriteLine(messageBody);
    }
}
```

And a similar file with the logic for recovery messages (*CustomCheckSucceeded*). You probably want a check in there to detect it is actually recovering from a failure, not just passing the test.

So anyway, fixed - on my dev pc.

The next problem was making it work on the server, which took a support call. It turns out ServiceControl ALSO needs a licence, available as part of the "Advanced", "Enterprise", and "Ultimate" editions - Not part of the platform on the standard licence.